# Lift won't prepend context path before link if I use `S.render`, how to fix it?

Tags: scala, lift

When deploy a lift app to a tomcat container, it will automatically pretend the context path to all the `<a>`s whose `href` are starting with "/". (How is lift doing this?)

But in my `Boot.scala`, I want to show a custom 500 page, that I use `S.render` to render a template, and found the links are not handled.

My code:

```
LiftRules.exceptionHandler.prepend {
  case (runMode, req, exception) =>
    logger.error("Failed at: " + req.uri, exception)
    val content = S.render(<lift:embed what="500"/>, req.request)
    XmlResponse(content.head, 500, "text/html", req.cookies)
}
```

You can see the line `S.render(<lift:embed what="500"/>, req.request)`

It will render the `webapp/500.html`, but without prepending the context path. When I deploy it to tomcat, the page can't show correctly since the js/css files can't load.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
val content = req.fixHtml(S.render(<lift:embed what="500"/>, req.request))
```

Notice the `req.fixHtml()`, it will prepend context path to the links if possible.